# AngularJS image upload with PUT, possible, how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS do upload an images with a PUT or Post request, is this possible, if so how as below does not change the header (still json) and there is no payload.

This is what I have tried:

in my controller:

```
       $scope.uploadFile = function (elm) {

            $scope.files = elm.files
            $scope.$apply();

            var fd = new FormData()
            fd.append('file', $scope.files[0])


            $scope.profile

                .customPOST(fd, "", ["Content-Type", undefined])
             .withHttpConfig({
                    transformRequest: angular.identity
                });

            event.preventDefault();


        };
```

html:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>
```

This code actually gets the file name and add its to the database, but no file actually gets uploaded during the put request.

Comment: you pass this.files to uploadFile(), but uploadFile() wants an element for _elm_, not a files collection. that might be your only issue from what i see posted in your question...

Answer (score 1):

This is the directive I like to use for my file uploads:
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

You can install it with bower: `bower install ng-file-upload --save`
It comes with many features like progress bar handling and easy drag and drop.

You can find examples on how to use it on the github link, but here's how I use it in [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) with AWS S3 direct upload. Just note that doing uploads to s3 takes a whole lot more of code. That also includes generating a token from the server.
Thats the `/api/media/upload_token` you see there.

```
$scope.processUpload = (metadata) ->
  $scope.fileUploads.push metadata
  $http.put('/api/media/' + metadata._id, metadata)
  .success (res) ->
    // do your stuff here when the upload is finished
    // $scope.reloadMedia();
  console.log metadata


$scope.onFileSelect = ($files) ->
  # merge new uploads, ignore old uploads
  $scope.files = $files;
  $scope.upload = [];
  # create a new closure for each file upload
  for file, i in $files
    file.progress = parseInt 0
    do (file, i) ->
      anticache = Math.random().toString(36).substring(3,9)
      $http.get('/api/media/upload_token?mimeType=' + file.type + '&rnd=' + anticache,
      {filename: file.name})
      .success (response) ->
        s3Params = response
        uploadData =
          url: 'https://<mybucketname>.s3.amazonaws.com/'
          method: 'POST'
          data:
            key: s3Params.filename + '$$' + file.name
            acl: 'public-read'
            'Content-Type': file.type
            AWSAccessKeyId: s3Params.AWSAccessKeyId
            success_action_status: 201
            Policy: s3Params.s3Policy
            Signature: s3Params.s3Signature
          file: file

        # start the upload
        $scope.upload[i] = $upload.upload(uploadData)
        .progress (evt) ->
          file.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)
        .success (res, status, headers, config) ->
          file.progress = parseInt 100
          if status is 201
            xmlDoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(res, 'application/xml')
            getXmlValue = (k) -> xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            metadata =
              _id: response.filename
              location: getXmlValue 'Location'
              bucket: getXmlValue 'Bucket'
              key: getXmlValue 'Key'
              etag: getXmlValue 'ETag'
              filename: file.name
            $scope.processUpload(metadata)
          else
            throw new Error("File Upload Failed! Server status is not 201");
            alert 'Upload Failed, please try again.'
```

This is my [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) view, just note that the classes I have are from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```
.form-group.well(ng-file-drop='onFileSelect($files)')
  span.btn.btn-primary.btn-file.btn-block
    | Upload Media
    input(type='file', ng-file-select='onFileSelect($files)', multiple)
  p.help-block You can also drag and drop files here.
  .row(ng-repeat='file in files')
    .col-md-8
      .progress
        .progress-bar(role='progressbar', style='width:{{file.progress}}%;')
            | {{file.name}} : {{file.progress}}
    .col-md-4
      button.btn.btn-warning(type='button', ng-click='abort($index)', ng-show='file.progress != 100') Abort
  div(ng-file-drop-available='dropSupported=true', ng-show='!dropSupported') HTML5 Drop File is not supported!
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload the image using AngularJS you can put the input tag in a form and submit the form.

So in the HTML your code should look like this:

```
<form id='uploadForm' enctype='multipart/form-data' method = 'post' name ='settingForm'>
    <input id='inputFile' type='file' name = 'uploadFile' />
    <button id='saveSetting' ng-click='onSubmit()' name='save'>Save</button>
</form>
```

Here you can notice the enctype set to multipart and method as post.

In the controller:

```
$scope.onSubmit = function() {
    var options = {
        target: '',
        url: '<your server url>',
        success: function() {
            //what ever you require on success
        }
    };
    $('#uploadForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
}
```

In the server you can get the file in the request parameter (in NodeJS it will look like this):

```
req.files.uploadFile;
```

where 'uploadFile' is the name that you specify in the HTML markup

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Did this help in your problem??

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular method like this,
HTML Part,

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" />
```

In your controller write this,

```
    $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
        var file = $files[0];
        // upload file to server
        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/yourpath',
            file: file
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // file is uploaded successfully
        }).error(function (data) {
            // file upload failed
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

HTML Part:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>
```

Angular part:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success( /*COOOOOOLLL*/ ).error( /*Use the force Luke!*/ );

};
```

OR if you want to add some progress bar you can try this with multiple file upload:

```
<div ng-controller="FileUploadCtrl">
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var FileUploadCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var file = $files[i];
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'server/upload/url', 
        data: {uploadObject: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: file,
      }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  };
}];
```

Comment: its states angular.identity is not defined.

Comment: i would also like to keep this in restangular if possible

Comment: Try to use this way angular.identity().

Comment: angular.identity() is still undefined for me

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me as I was looking for a solution to post file to Amazon S3. Worked with both `PUT` AND `POST` as method

```
$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: http://www.yourdomain.com/yourpath',
    data: file,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    },
    transformRequest : function (data, headersGetter) {
        return data;
    }
});
```