# AngularJS put method to upload files gives no data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, symfony

I have a [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) application that uses [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) on the front-end to upload files with ajax via the `POST` method.

### Working POST Method

The data is added as `FormData` and some `angular.identity` magic is used to auto populate the correct `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` content-type:

```
$scope.fileUpload = function (file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("title", file.title);
    fd.append("file", $scope.file);

    $http.post('example/upload', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then({
        // do something
    });
};
```

This works as expected allowing me to access the posted variables in my controller:

```
// Expects data from a post method
public function postFile(Request $request)
{
    $title = $request->get('title');
    /** @var $file UploadedFile */
    $file = $request->files->get('file');

    // data success, all is good
}
```

### Failing PUT Method

However when I do exactly the same using the `PUT` method, I get a `200` success but there is no accessible data:

```
$scope.fileUpload = function (file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("title", file.title);
    fd.append("file", $scope.file);

    $http.put('example/update', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then({
        // do something
    });
};
```

```
// Expects data from a put method
public function putFile(Request $request)
{
    $title = $request->get('title');
    /** @var $file UploadedFile */
    $file = $request->files->get('file');

    // the request parameters and query are empty, there is no accessible data
}
```

[image: AngularJS put body is empty]

The question is why does this occur with `PUT` but not `POST` and how can I get around this? I could use `POST` to update the file too but that's a hacky solution I'd like to avoid.

There are similar questions but no appropriate solutions that fix the issue whilst using `PUT`:

[Send file using PUT method Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116627/send-file-using-put-method-angularjs)

[AngularJS image upload with PUT, possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805874/angularjs-image-upload-with-put-possible-how)

[Angularjs file upload in put method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902220/angularjs-file-upload-in-put-method-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After delving further into this it appears this is a core PHP issue rather than a bug in AngularJS or Symfony.

The issue is that PHP PUT and PATCH do not parse the request so the content simply isn't available. (You can read more here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815)

A workaround to this is using the `POST` method but spoofing the method to be that of `PATCH/PUT` like so:

```
$scope.fileUpload = function (file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("title", file.title);
    fd.append("file", $scope.file);
    fd.append('_method', 'PUT');

    $http.post('example/update', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then({
        // do something
    });
};
```